# Get latest shape in ArrayList to paint on top of other shapes - Java

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, shapes, paintcomponent

Since this is schoolwork I do not want a complete solution but rather a push in the right direction on what I should be looking at (hence why there is no code).

I got a class that handle mouse input. From that class I check if user hold down mouse button on a shape and then set that shape to be the active shape. While the user drags the shape the shape moves along with it and changes position accordingly. Once the mouse is released the selectedShape is set to null and the panel is being repainted.

I want that the selectedShape is on top of all the other shapes, so if the selected shape is being dragged over any other shape it is infront.

From what I understand the repaint() method just repaint them as they appear in the ArrayList and I need to use another method to paint that shape at top (visually speaking).

Where would I go about to add this functionality? In the MouseHandler class?

Classes included that are relevant:
**MyShape** - Parent class
 **Triangle, Square, Circle** - Child - has its own draw(g) method and setPosition
**MouseHandler** - mouse movement and calls each shape to set new position.
**MyShapeHandler** - add/remove shapes from list
**Panel** - create instance of shapes and add to ArrayList using MyShapeHandler help method addShape. Draws each shape in ArrayList using drawComponent(g).
**Window** - JFrame that adds panel

Comment: If no particular order of the shape objects is required , you could just swap the last selected object and the last object in the arraylist using `set(index, object)` provided by the List interface. You should do that in your MouseHandler in the MouseReleased method.

Comment: Given how shapes may overlap or be entirely enclose by other shapes, I'd keep a separate list (as in a `JList`) of all the shapes. The list would allow selection of the 'current shape to move'. Then you might simply emulate it being on top by, when painting, first painting the entire list of shapes, then finally, painting the selected shape (a second time).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rearrange the list so that the desired shape is first/last. Experiment and see if the shape's index in the list corresponds to its location in the front or back on the screen.

Comment: That is a great idea, I have now replaced that selected shape to be last. Is there no handy method in ArrayList to switch 2 positions with each other? As it is now the last position (shapes.set(shape.size() - 1, selectedShape) gets replaced by this selectedShape (so the triangle gets removed completely)

Comment: I managed to get it to work by using Collections.swap(). Thanks alot! It works like a charm now. I am new here, is there anything I need to do like vote up answer or similar?

Comment: @VitalViper Great. You could up vote my answer, so that I can get some reputation :-) Additionally You can accept this answer as best one, so I can get even more reputation :-) Look here http://stackoverflow.com/tour for more details about this.